# Batch: Retrieve IP/host from tracert

Tags: batch-file, traceroute

Im trying to make a script which runs a tracert, and then performs a ping on every hop. Currently, the tracert troubles me, due to the fact that the variables changes all depending if the host is reachable or not.

A tracert performs a hop count, 3 pings and then post the address or hostname. If the hostname is unreachable, it might give out a * instead.

For example:

```
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.3.2.1
  2     *       <1 ms    <1 ms  FA0-0.100M.rc00-rhv.aplus.dk [62.61.128.142]
  3     *        1 ms     1 ms  hor2.ae15-cr1.danskkabeltv.dk [62.61.137.86]
  4     *        1 ms     1 ms  TE2-2.10G.rc02-hor.aplus.dk [62.61.138.44]
  5     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  speedtest01-hor.aplus.dk [62.61.131.22]
```

The above example, all the lines differ due to the 1 ms OR * if its delayed.

If written some code:

```
SET Dest=speedtest.danskkabeltv.dk
SET LineStart=1
SET LineEnd=30
FOR /F "tokens=1,8,9 delims= " %%A IN ('Tracert %Dest%') DO IF %%A GEQ %LineStart% IF %%A LEQ %LineEnd% (
@((timeout /t 2 /nobreak)>nul)
call :GetPing %%A %%B %%C )

pause
```

And:

```
A = Hop count
B = Hostname (Or IP address if no hostname)
C = IP address (If hostname is present)
```

This is only some of it.. But due to the fact that i rely on A B & C being those IP addresses and hostnames, i get the wrong results if i get * or so in the ms column.

I dont know how to search for the IP address, of if theres a way to do a for /f reversed, to get the last columns first?

Thanks :)

*EDIT*:

Hey guys, thanks for all the help. I've tried with some of the methods you guys used, but i can't really seem to get my result right.

As requested, the entire code & how i would like the results:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL disableDelayedExpansion
SET "Dest=speedtest.danskkabeltv.dk"
SET /a LineStart=1
SET /a LineEnd=30
FOR /F "delims=" %%X IN ('Tracert -w 300 %Dest%') DO (
CALL:GetTraceLine %%~X
)
pause
GOTO:EOF

:GetTraceLine (
SETLOCAL
if "%1"=="Tracing" ( 
    EXIT /b
)

SET "Line=%~1"
SET "Line=%Line: ms =%"
FOR /F "tokens=1,5,6 delims= " %%A IN ("%Line%") DO IF %1 GEQ %LineStart% IF %1 LEQ %LineEnd% (
SET /a Hop=%%A
SET /a HOST=%%B
SET /a IP=%%C

if "%HOP%"=="Tracing" ( 
    EXIT /b
)

if "%HOST%"=="Request" ( 
    echo Hop: %HOP% Packetloss: ---                Average: ---       Host: Timeout
    EXIT /b
)


if "%IP%"=="" ( 
    call :GetPing %%A %HOST%
    EXIT /b
)
ELSE (
        FOR /F "delims=[]" %%A IN ('%IP%') DO (
            set IP=%%A
        )  

    call :GetPing %%A %IP% %HOST%
    EXIT /b

    )

)

:GetPing (
SetLocal
@ECHO OFF
SET AVG=---
SET LOSS=---
SET TARGET=%2
SET TARGET2=%3
SET HOP=%1


SET PingCMD=ping.exe -w 300 -n 30 %TARGET%
FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%A IN ('%PingCMD%') DO (
        call :GetLoss %%A
        call :GetAvg %%A
)
echo Hop: %HOP% Packetloss: %loss%                Average: %avg%       Host: %TARGET% %TARGET2%
)
EXIT /b

:GetLoss
IF "%1"=="Lost" SET loss=%2 %3%% %4
EXIT /b
:GetAvg
IF "%1"=="Average" SET avg=%2 %3
EXIT /b
```

It doesnt seem to "skin" the first line, when i call GetTraceLine, im still getting "ms ms" in the line.

The result im after is this:

```
Hop: 1  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 0ms    IP: 192.168.1.1  
Hop: 2  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 0ms    IP: 10.59.17.1  
Hop: 3  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 2ms    IP: 172.17.2.137  
Hop: 4  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 6ms    IP: 172.17.4.36  
Hop: 5  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 4ms    IP: 172.17.4.10  
Hop: 6  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 2ms    IP: 172.17.4.3  
Hop: 7  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 3ms    IP: 80.72.159.241       Host: lt-0-0-0.mx-1a.ip.cirque.dk
Hop: 8  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 2ms    IP: 194.255.185.193     Host: 0xc2ffb9c1.linknet.dk.telia.net
Hop: 9  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 2ms    IP: 194.255.133.97      Host: 0xc2ff8561.linknet.dk.telia.net
Hop: 10 Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 5ms    IP: 194.255.133.98      Host: 0xc2ff8562.linknet.dk.telia.net 
Hop: 11 Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 3ms    IP: 87.72.143.234  
Hop: 12 Packetloss: ---             Average: ---    IP: Timeout
Hop: 13 Packetloss: ---             Average: ---    IP: Timeout
Hop: 14 Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 3ms    IP: 62.61.131.22        Host: speedtest01-hor.aplus.dk
```

I hope it makes more sense then :)

Again, thanks for all the help!

Comment: Do you want only the IP addresses, as your thread title says?

Comment: I would like hop count, hostname and ping retrieved (sry for the title :))

Comment: Edit your question and show before and after text.

Comment: I've edited my post as requested :)

Comment: It can be done with tracert using code to get the IP addresses, and then loop through them all again using ping to get the packetloss, average, and host names.  Your formatting won't be as structured when a couple of items vary to two/three digits.

Comment: Well, that's also what i've done so far :) .. It works too, but due to the fact that it can time out, it would make different results before the ping were performed - and thus, not get the IP address properly in the tracert.

Comment: Did you notice my changed answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=5 delims=ms " %a in ('tracert -4 -d speedtest01-hor.aplus.dk ^|find " ms "') do @echo %a
```

For usage inside batch file double all percent signs.

Comment: search for " ms ". "ms" could be part of an internet address.

Comment: @Stephan, sorry, i forget the header of the tracert.

Comment: @Endoro, have i missed anything now?

Comment: @foxidrive, Why is it not going to return the IP address?

Comment: My understanding is that the OP only wants the IP addresses, as the title says.

Comment: @foxidrive, ok, And what does the posted code return?

Comment: My mistake.  It does return only the IP addresses so the `-d` does that.

Comment: @foxidrive, no, the `-d` switch in the tracert command disables the name resolution.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q22639584.txt) DO SET "line=%%a"&CALL :process

GOTO :EOF

:process
SET "line=%line:<=%"
CALL :select %line%
ECHO %A%+%B%+%C%
GOTO :eof

:select
SET A=%1
:selectl
shift
SET "B=%1"
SET "C=%2"
SET "line=%3"
IF DEFINED line GOTO selectl
IF %c:~0,1%==[ (SET "c=%c:~1,-1%") else (SET "B=")
GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q22639584.txt` containing your data for my testing.

The lines are reported with `+` characters between the fields.

It would have been good if you'd shown us what you wanted as a result. I'm just assuming that

```
1++10.3.2.1
2+FA0-0.100M.rc00-rhv.aplus.dk+62.61.128.142
3+hor2.ae15-cr1.danskkabeltv.dk+62.61.137.86
4+TE2-2.10G.rc02-hor.aplus.dk+62.61.138.44
5+speedtest01-hor.aplus.dk+62.61.131.22
```

is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL disableDelayedExpansion
SET "Dest=speedtest.danskkabeltv.dk"
SET /a LineStart=1
SET /a LineEnd=30
FOR /F "delims=" %%X IN (FILE) DO CALL:GetTraceLine "%%~X"
GOTO:EOF

:GetTraceLine
SETLOCAL
SET "Line=%~1"
SET "Line=%Line: ms =%"
FOR /F "tokens=1,5,6 delims= " %%A IN ("%Line%") DO IF %%A GEQ %LineStart% IF %%A LEQ %LineEnd% (
    call :GetPing %%A %%B %%C
)
EXIT /b

:GetPing
SETLOCAL
ECHO(%~1 %~2 %~3
EXIT /b
```

---

output is:

```
1 10.3.2.1
2 FA0-0.100M.rc00-rhv.aplus.dk [62.61.128.142]
3 hor2.ae15-cr1.danskkabeltv.dk [62.61.137.86]
4 TE2-2.10G.rc02-hor.aplus.dk [62.61.138.44]
5 speedtest01-hor.aplus.dk [62.61.131.22]
```

---

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) - one liner:

```
for /f %a in ('tracert -4 -d stackoverflow.com ^|sed -r "/\sms\s/!d; s/.*\s(.+)/\1/"') do @echo %a
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives the kind of information asked for in the updated question but not quite the desired formatting.

It relies on English language for the ping results. Tested in Windows 8.1

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "file=%temp%\tr999.tmp"
call :tr speedtest01-hor.aplus.dk
pause
goto :EOF
:tr
echo performing tracert to %1
for /f "skip=2 tokens=1,5 delims=ms " %%a in ('tracert -4 -d %1 ^|findstr "[0-9]"') do (
 if /i not "%%b" == "Reque" (
   set Packetloss=
   set average=*
   set host=
   echo checking hop %%a to %%b
   ping -a -n 4 %%b > "%file%"
   for /f "tokens=2" %%f in ('findstr "Pinging" ^< "%file%"') do set host=%%f
   for /f "tokens=4 delims==" %%f in ('findstr "Lost" ^< "%file%"') do set packetloss=%%f
   for /f "tokens=4 delims==" %%f in ('findstr "Average" ^< "%file%"') do set average=%%f
   >> "%file%.txt" echo Hop: %%a - Packetloss: !packetloss:~0,-1! - Average: !average! - IP: %%b - Host: !host! 
 ) else (
   >> "%file%.txt" echo Hop: %%a - *** timed out ***
 )
)
echo done
echo.
type "%file%.txt"
copy "%file%.txt" ".\tracert results.txt" >nul
del "%file%" "%file%.txt"
```